# google sheet query, extract a range of cells from a range of columns

Tags: google-sheets, range, multiple-columns, cell

Firts of all hi everyone
I'm new of this forum and I have a very low experience of the powerful gooogle sheet query
My problem is to get a range of cells from a range of columns.
In the shared file here
[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3UhNZjSbYck2MKptE8kd_2_Jj6UkFZbaIWI8kMsevs/edit?usp=sharing)
there are 103 rows of numbers subdivided in 6 columns.
My scope is for every number in column I have the list of the date of extraction.

I tried with =query(A:G;"select A,I where {B:G}=I") but evidently...
Thank you for your kindly support

Comment: Hi, trying to learning query rules I did this formula =query({A:G};"select Col1 where "Col"&arrayformula(TEXTJOIN(" OR Col";;SEQUENCE(1;6;2)&"="&""&I2&""))")  that unfortunatle with arrayformula and Text join doesn't work, but copy/paste the result of that formula works properly. Here the [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3UhNZjSbYck2MKptE8kd_2_Jj6UkFZbaIWI8kMsevs/edit#gid=1401842419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3UhNZjSbYck2MKptE8kd_2_Jj6UkFZbaIWI8kMsevs/edit#gid=1401842419) you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(;1);tocol(I2:I;1);lambda(a;c;{a;c;tocol(index(if(B:G=c;text(A:A;"dd-mmm-yyyy");));1)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive, I was trying with query but this seems very smart. Maybe when I've studied queries enough, I'll find a method